# Email addresses with GET parameters (or equivalent)

Tags: php, linux, email, http

I could send someone an email using PHP which contains a link, and when clicked, identify the specific email that they clicked the link on, update the database, etc by including a link such as the following where `123j12345k345jk3452sdfg` identifies the email:

```
<a href="http://example.com?task=updateSomething&amp;id=123j12345k345jk3452sdfg">Update My Stuff</a>
```

Instead of having them click a link in the email, I wish to allow the recipient of the email to be able to reply to the email, and allow PHP to receive the returned email and identify the specific email that they replied to.

Is doing so possible, and if so, how?

Comment: its possible but a lot more work the original idea is much better if you ask me

Comment: to do, you would need to pipe all mail to a certain address to a php script then parse the email fro the data. how you set up the first part depends on your hosting environment and mail server

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is relatively trivial. The only catch is that is that normally php is running in/from a webserver. There's 2 obvious ways to get the reply back to PHP:

Running a script as a daemon or via a cron job, poll the mailbox using pop/IMAP and scan the mails for a pattern containing your verification code. This is a bit simpler if it has some well defined characteristics, e.g. 40 hexadecimal digits enclosed in square brackets, of perhaps a shorter pattern specifically in the subject line.

Alternatively implement a filter on the SMTP MTA using PHP. I have done this in the past using a procmail delivery rule but it is also possible to invoke your script from a milter.

Comment: Maybe PHP should not be used?  My main objective is to update a database which PHP happens to query.  I don't like using the subject line (or body) as the user inadvertently might change it.  Using a FROM email and a REPLY TO email might work?  Or is their some other was to associate parameters with an email.

Comment: Yes, you could embed the token in the reply address, but this has some constraints in its applicability - code can only be implemented on a wildcard mailbox which is not available everywhere. And yes, you could implement it in any language you like, but it is rather silly to use multiple languages without a good reason. You did state that you required to correlate the reply to a specific outgoing email.